# I get id of undefined error at the end when all the files are processed

Tags: angular, typescript

In simple words the beow code is supposed to fetched the progress of currently running file which gets processed in the backend. It does everything which it is supposed to do. But at the end when all the files are processed which means when the length of this.currentlyRunning.length is 0 after then i get an error in the console "index of undefined" in this line

```
let file_id = {
      userFileId: this.currentlyRunning[index].id
    }
```

The code calls the api get progress again and again for all the files that is in the currentlyRunning array till 100% progress is reached. Thats why I have used setInterval.
 Lets say there are two files in the list of Currently Running, The get progress method will be called after every 4000 miliseconds and the progress for each file is updated in the view. After both the files are processed then the error is thrown on the console "index of undefined"

```
checkProgress() {
            let index = 0;
            let repeat = setInterval(() => {
              let numberOfFiles = this.currentlyRunning.length;
              if(numberOfFiles === 0) {
                clearInterval(repeat);
              }
            let file_id = {
              userFileId: this.currentlyRunning[index].id
            }
              this.auth.getProgress(file_id).subscribe((res: any)=>{
                    this.currentlyRunning[index]['progress'] = Math.round(res.percent);
                    let indexOfFileHistory =  this.uploadedFileHistory.findIndex((file: any)=> file.id === this.currentlyRunning[index].id);
                    this.uploadedFileHistory[indexOfFileHistory] = this.currentlyRunning[index];
                    if(this.currentlyRunning[index].progress === 100 || res.status == "badBounceRate") {
                      //the origial array which contains all the files we are just updating its status on 100% individual file object is returned with updated status
                      this.uploadedFileHistory[indexOfFileHistory] = res.data;
                      //removing the file from currently running
                      this.currentlyRunning.splice(index, 1);

                    }
                    //incrementing so that next time it runs for the other file
                    index  = index + 1;
                      if(index >= numberOfFiles) {
                        index = 0;
                      }
                      let running =  this.uploadedFileHistory.find((file: any)=>file.status === "Running");
                      if(!running) {
                        clearInterval(repeat);
                    }
                 },(err)=>{ 
                 //want to run it regardless of the error
                  index  = index + 1;
                    if(index >= numberOfFiles) {
                      index = 0;
                    }
                    let running =  this.uploadedFileHistory.find((file: any)=>file.status === "Running");
                    if(!running) {
                      clearInterval(repeat);
                   }
                });
            }, 4000);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe after:

```
if(numberOfFiles === 0) {
   clearInterval(repeat);
   return; // <-- stop further processing
}
```